# Check if JSON object is similar to a part in the URL

Tags: jquery, json

This is a part of my JSON file

```
"hotels" : [
    {
      "ID" : 100,
      "pageURL" : "brisbane.php",
      "SupplierName" : "Hilton Brisbane",
    }
    {
      "ID" : 101,
      "pageURL" : "gold-coast.php",
      "SupplierName" : "Hilton Gold Coast",
    }
```

These are my URLs

```
website.com/brisbane.php
website.com/gold-coast.php
```

**What Im trying to do**

When I visit brisbane.php, I am checking the URL to see if `pageURL` exists in the url with this script

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf(f.pageURL) > -1){
    //pull all the objects with f.pageURL and show them on the page
}
```

Then I want to print all the objects with "brisbane.php" as the `pageURL` on my website with jQuery.

**What Im stuck at**

I dont know how to pull all the objects with 'brisbane.php' in the 'pageURL' .In other words I want to grab everything from the JSON file that has `pageURL` as `brisbane.php`

Do I have to pull the string out of the URL and compare it to the `pageURL`?

Can you help?

Comment: So you got `f.pageURL` (say, brisbane.php) and you want to grab the object of `ID` 100?

Comment: No. I can grab the ID with my script

`$.getJSON('deals.json', function(data) {
     $.each(data.hotels, function(i, f) {` 
I want to grab everything with the f.pageURL set as 'brisbane.php' in the JSON file

Comment: How about creating an array before the loop and push the object having a specific `pageURL` in the loop? Do you want an example of doing that?

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol I managed to get it to work. see below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return a filtered array matching the pageURL key. Let's say your hotels JSON is stored in a variable `json`, and you want to match against the string "brisbane.php", then the following should filter your JSON array of objects and return an array of objects that match the appropriate key, and log it to the console.

```
var match = "brisbane.php";

console.log(json.hotels.filter(function(elem) {
  return (elem.pageURL == match);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all I had to do to solve the problem.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf(f.pageURL) > -1) {

            var currentPageURL = f.pageURL;

            if(f.pageURL = currentPageURL ){
                console.log(f.SupplierName);
            }

         }
```

This simply displayed all the suppliers with brisbane.php while on that page.